# Is the function wrong?

Tags: java, oop

[image: Wants to print number of digits of the input]

```
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();

    while(n>0) {
        int count=0;
        n= n/10;
        count++;

    }
    System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: declare int count = 0; before the while loop

Comment: Really great. Can you also tell me how to find this thing that where to initialize. I mean is there any trick to check this thing. Sorry I just started few days back.

Comment: @Varun Chawla please learn to use `debugger`, it'll tell you where to initialize properly and solve many small issues in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you have declared the variable `count` in the `while` loop block and so it is a local variable and the scope of the variable is limited till `while` loop block.

If you want the program to execute successfully, you should declare the variable inside the `main` method block but outside the `while` loop block.

Like this

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int count = 0;
    while(n > 0){
        n = n/10;
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println("Count = "+count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scope of a variable is the part of the program where the variable is accessible.
Refer this article for more details [Scope in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/)

Also to correct the code,

```
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int count = 0;

    while(n>0) {
        count=0;
        n= n/10;
        count++;

    }
    System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Compile error `The local variable count may not have been initialized`